# What is the rule on licensing and third party code?

Tags: 8

When you create a module that uses third party code, is there any instance in which it is "okay" to include it in the module as opposed to have the user download it themselves?

For instance, if you make a module that integrates a CKEditor plugin - I would think that you *can't* or rather, *shouldn't* put it into your module on drupal.org.

I see this here: https://www.drupal.org/node/422996

My gut tells me it is likely not good practice to bundle it up into your module.

Comment: You could ask for an explicit permission from the 3rd party code owner.

Comment: Are you asking about a module that you want to put on drupal.org or one that you are delivering in a different way?

Comment: Someone raised an issue saying I could 'put the ckeditor plugin' into the module because the plugin is GPL. Not that I want to do it, but wanted clarification.

Comment: @Kevin the main issue with doing that, and why it's not permitted is that if they release an update, you have to release an update. This makes for your code to become outdated quickly.  In change, if it's something outside of your project, and it doesn't change any interfaces, you don't have to modify your project and they can just update when they want the library.

Answer (score 2):

> My gut tells me it is likely not good practice to bundle it up into your module.

You shouldn't. That page starts out with:

> This is the policy for 3rd party code libraries in Drupal's contribution repositories.
>
> > In general 3rd party libraries and content are forbidden, so do not commit any. Instead, document for your users how to find and install the library/content themselves.

The other way is exceptions and they're clearly defined and you need to request approval.

Comment: Anyone may use GPL-compatible licensed code within GPL code, but this is against drupal.org's policy (except the whitelisted libraries) for contributed modules, themes and install profiles (distributions). If the person distributing the code does so outside of drupal.org, there is no licensing issue. However I think that it is a good idea to distribute dependencies separately in case another module does want to depend on the same library, and dependencies aren't duplicated on a site.

Comment: If it's a library, even if GPLv2+ or GPLv2+ compatible, in order to get added, it needs an explicit exception. Here's the quote, from the same link that @Kevin posted, _Getting an exception needs explicit approval by Drupal Licensing Working Group (LWG). Exception requests should be posted in the LWG's issue queue with the component "Exception Request". (Upfront: 90% of all exception requests are moot. Only ask for an exception if it is really required.) _

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's why I said it is "against drupal.org's policy (except the whitelisted libraries)". Not sure why the response to my comment? It is perfectly acceptable however to distribute code outside of drupal.org with GPL-compatible code in GPL licensed module.

Comment: Umm.. I have no idea what I read or what went through my head. You're totally right.

Comment: And further, you can have your git privileges on d.o revoked if you violate this policy: http://drupal.org/node/1001544